# How to handle multidimensional array as @RequestParam in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, arrays, spring, spring-mvc

So, basically, I have a form that sends the following inputs:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="days[monday][start]" value="1">
  <input type="text" name="days[monday][end]" value="2">
  <input type="text" name="days[tuesday][start]" value="1">
  <input type="text" name="days[tuesday][end]" value="2">
</form>
```

How to handle this in Spring MVC as `@RequestParam`?

So far I tried

```
@RequestParam(value= "days", required = true) Map<String, Object>[] days
......
@RequestParam(value= "days", required = true) Map<String, Map<String, Object>> days
... or even ...
request.getParameter("days");
```

But without success.

Comment: can you please share how are you sending this array data from the form

Comment: I just added a sample HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to wrap that in a custom object , which will hold the Map object. Then you will have to change the submit and initialization of your form.

```
public class CustomWrapper{

    private Map<String, Object> customMap= new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public Map<String, Object> getCustomMap() {
        return customMap;
    }

    public void setCustomMap(Map<String, Object> customMap) {
        this.customMap = customMap;
    }

}

@RequestParam("days") CustomWrapper days
```

More info [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-hashmap-form-example/)

Answer (score 1):

try something like below:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void method(@RequestParam(value = "param[][]") String[][] paramValues)
{
    // rest of your code
}
```